# Protractor test in Angular 6 for angular 6 material data table

Tags: protractor, angular-material, angular6, gulp-protractor

My angular application has the data list view which has been developed by the Angular material data table as below.

```
<mat-table class="lessons-table mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="role">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Role</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell class="description-cell"
                          *matCellDef="let user">{{user.role}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Email</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell class="description-cell fontSize10px"
                      *matCellDef="let user" matTooltip="{{user.email}}">

                      {{showEmail(user.email)}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

Here, How do I check in this page using Protractor? Anyone help me this?

Comment: check what ? please give more information about your goal

Comment: How do i check my data set is correct ?

Comment: give us an example of data you are trying to verify.

Comment: Protractor generally can query the dom. I would also like to see what you have tried. Please provide an example of what you are doing. Also are you using Protractor or gulp-protractor? Just checking in on the tags...